# How can I prove that $40/29<\sqrt{2}<42/29$ given $20<29/\sqrt{2}<21$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

How can I prove that $40/29<\sqrt{2}<42/29$ given $20<29/\sqrt{2}<21$?

I did lot of approaches I obtained in one that: $$\dfrac{29}{42}<\sqrt{2}<\dfrac{29}{10}$$ but couldn't do something other
Thank you.

Comment: Multiply each term in the given inequalities by $2/29$.

Comment: This question seems to have received the most answers in the least amount of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$20<\frac{29}{\sqrt{2}}<21$ implies $\frac{20}{29}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}<\frac{21}{29}$. So, if we multiply everything by $2$. then,  $\frac{40}{29}<\sqrt{2}<\frac{42}{29}$

Answer (score 1):

$$20<\dfrac{29}{\sqrt{2}}<21\iff 20 <\dfrac{29}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}<21 \\ \iff 20<\dfrac{29}{2}\sqrt{2}<21 \\ \iff \dfrac{40}{29}<\sqrt{2}<\dfrac{42}{29}$$

Comment: I found the solution just after I posted the question!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: write $29/2^{1/2}= 29\cdot 2^{1/2}/2$

Answer (score 0):

$$20<29/\sqrt{2}<21\\
20<29/\sqrt{2}\mbox{ and }29/\sqrt{2}<21$$
Write
$$29/\sqrt{2}=(29\cdot\sqrt{2})/2$$
Then,
$$20<(29\cdot\sqrt{2})/2\mbox{ and }(29\cdot\sqrt{2})/2<21\\
40<(29\cdot\sqrt{2})\mbox{ and }(29\cdot\sqrt{2})<42\\
40/29<\sqrt{2}\mbox{ and }\sqrt{2}<42/29\\
\mbox{Thus }40/29<\sqrt{2}<42/29$$
Q.E.D.

Answer (score 0):

Simply divide both sides of the given inequality by 29 mutiply by 2. Note that $2/\sqrt{2}=\sqrt{2}$